# plot interpolate a curve between 2 different types of curves in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following data that predicts a curve in the middle of the two curves which has different equation and datas.I also need to spline and smothen the curve of the middle curve
I've tried searching other codes here in stackoverflow but this is the most close to the right solution. So far the plot for the two curve is right but the interpolated point gives me wrong plot.

Im trying to find the plot for  val=30  given that (a25,vel25)=25  and   (a50,vel50)=50. Please help me troubleshoot and get a table of data (x,y) for the generated interpolated curve. Thanks for your help
[generated plot using this program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uanf3.png)

```
a50=[1.05
0.931818182
0.931818182
0.968181818
1.045454545
1.136363636
1.354545455
1.568181818
1.718181818
1.945454545
2.159090909
2.454545455
2.772727273
];
vel50=[0.85
0.705555556
0.605555556
0.533333333
0.472222222
0.45
0.427777778
0.45
0.477777778
0.533333333
0.611111111
0.711111111
0.827777778
];
a25=[0.5
0.613636364
0.686363636
0.795454545
0.918181818
0.963636364
1.090909091
1.236363636
1.304545455
1.431818182
1.545454545
1.659090909
1.818181818
];
vel25=[0.425555556
0.354444444
0.302222222
0.266666667
0.233333333
0.226666667
0.211111111
0.222222222
0.237777778
0.266666667
0.311111111
0.35
0.402222222
];
plot(a25,vel25,'b-');
hold on
plot(a50,vel50,'g-');
minX = min([a25 a50]);
maxX = max([a25,a50]);
xx = linspace(minX,maxX,100);
vel25_inter = interp1(a25,vel25,xx);
vel50_inter = interp1(a50,vel50,xx);
val = 30; % The interpolated point
interpVel = vel25_inter + ((val-25).*(vel50_inter-vel25_inter))./(50-25);
plot(xx,interpVel,'r-');
```

Comment: I would suggest you to look at this question (and the answers) : [Interpolation between two curves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494254/interpolation-between-two-curves-matlab/23497688#23497688)

Comment: been there already and tried my data using those codes but it generates diff result. I just need to troubleshoot the code above because so far this solution is the most approximate to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question and answer linked in comment still apply and can be a solution.

In your case, it is not so direct because your data are not on the same grid and some are not monotonic, but once they are packaged properly, the easiest solution is still to use `griddata`.

By packaged properly, I mean finding the maximum common interval (on `x`, or what you call `a`), so the data can be interpolated between curve without producing `NaN`s.

This seems to work:
[image: curve interp]
The red dashed line is the values interpolated at `val=30`, all the other lines are interpolations for values between 25 to 50.

The code to get there:

```
% back up original data, just for final plot
bkp_a50 = a50 ; bkp_vel50 = vel50 ;

% make second x vector monotonic
istart = find( diff(a50)>0 , 1 , 'first') ;
a50(1:istart-1) = [] ;
vel50(1:istart-1) = [] ;

% prepare a 3rd dimension vector (from 25 to 50)
T = [repmat(25,size(a25)) ; repmat(50,size(a50)) ] ;
% merge all observations together
A = [  a25 ;   a50] ;
V = [vel25 ; vel50] ;

% find the minimum domain on which data can be interpolated
% (anything outside of that will return NaN)
Astart = max( [min(a25) min(a50)] ) ;
Astop  = min( [max(a25) max(a50)] ) ;

% use the function 'griddata'
[TI,AI] = meshgrid( 25:50 , linspace(Astart,Astop,10)  ) ; 
VI = griddata(T,A,V,TI,AI) ;

% plot all the intermediate curves
plot(AI,VI)
hold on
% the original curves
plot(a25,vel25,'--k','linewidth',2)
plot(bkp_a50,bkp_vel50,'--k','linewidth',2)
% Highlight the curve at T = 30 ;
c30 = find( TI(1,:) == 30 ) ;
plot(AI(:,c30),VI(:,c30),'--r','linewidth',2)
```

Comment: this is perfect @Hoki. how can I also get the interpolated data for c30?

Answer (score 0):

There were quite a few issues with your code that's why it was not executing properly. I have just made very little changes to your code and made it running,

```
clc
%13
a50=[1.05
0.931818182
0.932
0.968181818
1.045454545
1.136363636
1.354545455
1.568181818
1.718181818
1.945454545
2.159090909
2.454545455
2.772727273
];
%13
vel50=[0.85
0.705555556
0.605555556
0.533333333
0.472222222
0.45
0.427777778
0.45
0.477777778
0.533333333
0.611111111
0.711111111
0.827777778
];
%13
a25=[0.5
0.613636364
0.686363636
0.795454545
0.918181818
0.963636364
1.090909091
1.236363636
1.304545455
1.431818182
1.545454545
1.659090909
1.818181818
];
%13
vel25=[0.425555556
0.354444444
0.302222222
0.266666667
0.233333333
0.226666667
0.211111111
0.222222222
0.237777778
0.266666667
0.311111111
0.35
0.402222222
];
plot(a25,vel25,'b-');
hold on
plot(a50,vel50,'g-');
minX = min([a25 a50])
maxX = max([a25 a50])
%xx = linspace(minX,maxX);
xx = linspace(0.5,2.7727,100);
vel25_inter = interp1(a25,vel25,xx);
vel50_inter = interp1(a50,vel50,xx);
val = 30; % The interpolated point
interpVel = vel25_inter + ((val-25).*(vel50_inter-vel25_inter))./(50-25);
plot(xx,interpVel,'r-');
```

There issues were

1. The interval on which you wanted to interpolate is `xx = linspace(minX,maxX);` but it gives an error of the type,

> Matrix dimensions must agree.

Because you were assigning two values for the starting point and two for the ending point. So I replace it with `xx = linspace(0.5,2.7727,100);` where the starting point is being the minimum of the two minimum `minX` and the same for `maxX`

2. There are values of `a50` (0.931818182) that repeat  which was producing the following error

> The grid vectors are not strictly monotonic increasing.

I change one of the value and replaced it with `0.932`

The output is not that promising but is suppose the one you want?

[image]

Comment: yes this is the closest, but  i need the red curve appear same as the other two. can you check where is the error in this other solution also .Thanks

Comment: @user183060 If I could I would?

Comment: thanks. I also edited the code 'interpVel =vel25_inter + (vel50_inter-vel25_inter)/(50-25)' . I think this is where the problem starts.

Comment: @user183060 I tried but no luck to improve what I already had. Really sorry mate!. I hope someone else on this forum will come up with your desired answer. GOODLUCK!

Comment: thank you for the help .I really Hope that someone else will notice this.