# intersection of interpolated line and an interpolated curve matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, intersection, curve

I have a[straightline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUvma.png) with the following data

```
xinter=[1.13 1.36 1.62 1.81 2.00 2.30 2.61 2.83 3.05 3.39]
yinter=[0.10 0.25 0.40 0.50 0.60 0.75 0.90 1.00 1.10 1.25]
```

and I want to find the intersection with a result of an interpolated data
of a curve such as below

```
      a50=  [0.77 0.73 0.77 0.85 0.91 0.97 1.05 1.23 1.43 1.53 1.62 1.71 1.89 2.12 2.42];
a25=  [0.51 0.60 0.70 0.80 0.85 0.90 0.96 1.09 1.23 1.30 1.36 1.41 1.53 1.67];
vel25=[0.43 0.35 0.30 0.27 0.25 0.24 0.22 0.21 0.22 0.24 0.25 0.27 0.30 0.35];
vel50=[0.68 0.57 0.49 0.43 0.40 0.38 0.36 0.34 0.36 0.38 0.40 0.43 0.49 0.57 0.68 ];


% back up original data, just for final plot
bkp_a50 = a50 ; bkp_vel50 = vel50 ;

% make second x vector monotonic
istart = find( diff(a50)>0 , 1 , 'first') ;
a50(1:istart-1) = [] ;
vel50(1:istart-1) = [] ;

% prepare a 3rd dimension vector (from 25 to 50)
T = [repmat(25,size(a25)) ; repmat(40,size(a50)) ] ;
% merge all observations together
A = [  a25 ;   a50] ;
V = [vel25 ; vel50] ;

% find the minimum domain on which data can be interpolated
% (anything outside of that will return NaN)
Astart = max( [min(a25) min(a50)] ) ;
Astop  = min( [max(a25) max(a50)] ) ;

% use the function 'griddata'
[TI,AI] = meshgrid( 25:40 , linspace(Astart,Astop,10)  ) ; 
VI = griddata(T,A,V,TI,AI) ;

% plot all the intermediate curves
%plot(AI,VI)
hold on
% the original curves
%plot(a25,vel25,'--k','linewidth',2)
%plot(bkp_a50,bkp_vel50,'--k','linewidth',2)
% Highlight the curve at T = 30 ;
c30 = find( TI(1,:) == 40 ) ;
plot(AI(:,c30),VI(:,c30),'--r','linewidth',2)

xinter=[1.13 1.36 1.62 1.81 2.00 2.30 2.61 2.83 3.05 3.39]
yinter=[0.10 0.25 0.40 0.50 0.60 0.75 0.90 1.00 1.10 1.25]


x1inter=(AI(:,c30))';
y1inter=(VI(:,c30))';


yy2 = interp1(xinter, yinter, x1inter,'spline')


plot(xinter,yinter, '--k','linewidth',2)

 idx = find((y1inter - yy2) < eps, 1); %// Index of coordinate in array
 px = x1inter(idx)
py = y1inter(idx)
plot(px, py, 'ro', 'MarkerSize', 18)
```

But there is an error in the result when I modify `x1inter`

Comment: What is the red curve in your image? `x1inter` doesn't seem to have the same bounds as in your code

Comment: yes only in this code but in matlab I defined y1inter

Comment: In the sample code you give there is no intersection..

Comment: the intersection should be an interpolated value

Comment: Read how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: derived from interpolating both curve and line

Comment: Do you mean extrapolated?

Comment: Because for now the red curve is well above the black one..

Comment: `Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.`

Comment: @BillBokeey I added the full code in matlab to better illustrate what i mean. thanks

Comment: You don't define `yy2` in the code you posted

Comment: You don't define `eps` neither

Comment: I just added the more latest code I have but so far it produce the same result

Comment: So far it gives an error

Answer (score -1):

You can use piecewise polynomial curvefitting and the `fzero` function to find the intersection point:

```
pp1 = pchip(xinter,yinter);         % Curve 1
pp2 = pchip(AI(:,c30),VI(:,c30));   % Curve 2
fun = @(x) ppval(pp1,x) - ppval(pp2,x); % Curve to evaluate
xzero = fzero(fun,mean(xinter)) % intersection x value
yzero = ppval(pp1,xzero)
plot(xzero, yzero, 'bo', 'MarkerSize', 18)
```

Comment: the result is not excatly producing the result but its very close it should be xzero =1.36,  yzero=.25

Comment: I also zoomed in your plot and the marker is not really in the intersection point. Thanks

Comment: The marker is not on the intersection point, because your plot uses linear interpolation. The calculated intersection point however is calculated with the Piecewise Cubic Hermite Interpolating Polynomial.

Your intersection point (1.36 / 0.25) is given somewhere and you have to prove it?

Comment: its working only the lower point of the interpolated data using c30 = find( TI(1,:) == 25) ;   but if I use c30 = find( TI(1,:) == 40 ) ;   it doesn't produce the exact intersection. It should be the xzero and yzero =(1.36, .25)  for   c30 = find( TI(1,:) == 25) and (1.62,0.40) as in the data

Comment: Hello, I think it is a question what is for you the "exact intersection". Do you want to have the point on a discrete datapoint or a interpolation between 2 datapoints? As far as I can see is the point [1.36 | 0.25] a discrete point on the black curve. But this point is not the intersection point (but it is the closest). 
I chose interpolation to calculate the intersection point and get [1.38 | 0.26] for c30 = find( TI(1,:) == 25) and [1.64 | 0.41] for c30 = find( TI(1,:) == 40 ).

Comment: Yes I want the exact  interpolation for max value c30 = find( TI(1,:) == 40 ) which should be the px and py =(1.36, .25),    and for the minimum value c30 = find( TI(1,:) == 25) is  (1.62,0.40). And for c30 = find( TI(1,:) == 30)  should be equal to the interpolated intersection of curve 1 and straight line

Comment: please refer to the background about the in initial part of the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989753/plot-interpolate-a-curve-between-2-different-types-of-curves-in-matlab