# Interpolation between curves that may overlap

Tags: matlab, interpolation, curve

I try to interpolate curves in the gaps of some already existing curves using matlab (and the interp1-function).

*Start of edit 1*

I already have the data of 5 Torque over rpm curves that I obtained with a number of simulations for each curve. Since simulation time is precious, I would like to save time with the interpolation of curves that "fill the gap" between the already existing ones.

[image: img]

I'm looking to form the following:

[image: img]

Further thoughts of me down below.

*End of edit 1*

I tried to follow the steps from the question in the thread [Interpolation between two curves (matlab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494254/interpolation-between-two-curves-matlab) but it does not seem to work with my code. I am not sure if the code is actually applicable since the curves *might* overlap...

I tried to edit the code from the link above like the following:

```matlab
% Save the data in one array each. The original data is stored in the
% arrays "x/yOriginal" row-wise.
curve1_data = [xOriginal(:,1) yOriginal(:,1)];
curve2_data = [xOriginal(:,2) yOriginal(:,2)];

% This was to try if the code from the link works
yy = [0:1:60];

xx1 = interp1(curve1_data(:,2),curve1_data(:,1),yy,'spline');
xx2 = interp1(curve2_data(:,2),curve2_data(:,1),yy,'spline');
m = 3; % Curve_Offset
mm(:,m) = xx1 + (xx2-xx1)*(m/(8750-5000));

% With the following I tried to interpolate over x
xx = (xOriginal(1,1):1:xOriginal(1,2));

yy1 = interp1(curve1_data(:,1),curve1_data(:,2),xx,'spline');
yy2 = interp1(curve2_data(:,1),curve2_data(:,2),xx,'spline');


m = 3; % Curve_Offset
% From the original code:
mm(:,m) = xx1 + (xx2-xx1)*(m/(8750-5000));

% Interpolation over x
yINT = yy1 + (yy2-yy1)*(m/8750-5000);
```

None of the interpolation-techniques worked, the y-values are either 90% negative (with the code from the link) or way too high (10e8 with the interpolation over x).

What I expected was that it creates a curve a little less steep than the curve "to its left" and a bit steeper than the curve "to its right".

*My further thoughts:*

The existing curves are the product of big 3-dimensional arrays. I.e. it could be that it is more the way to go to interpolate the arrays and **then** "read out" the Torque-over-rpm-Curves. On the other hand, I don't see a way to interpolate between two 1001-by-7001-by-5 arrays...
Moreover, for the next steps with the programm, the curve-interpolation needs to be quite fine (it is necessary to have way more than 1 interpolated curve between two existing curves) which makes the problem even more difficult.

Comment: What does the picture illustrate? What parts of that image do you have, what parts of it don't you have, what is the picture you hope to get out at the end? [Can you update your question to make that clearer?](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks, I added another picture that hopefully helps others to understand. Additionally, I added another thought of me (which still did not help me, unfortunately..).

Comment: note that you don't need to be able to _post_ pictures, just read the markdown syntax help and you see that you just need to use the `![alt text](link to the image)` format to include an image in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, the plot is generated with something like this:

```matlab
plot(xOriginal(:,1),yOriginal(:,1))
plot(xOriginal(:,2),yOriginal(:,2))
% ...
```

If so, you can plot an intermediate curve with

```matlab
plot((xOriginal(:,1) + xOriginal(:,2))/2, (yOriginal(:,1) + yOriginal(:,2))/2)
```

That is, the average between each pair of coordinates forms a curve that is exactly half-way between the two original curves.

Use weighted averages to generate more of these curves. This is linear interpolation.

```matlab
d = 0.2;
plot(d*xOriginal(:,1) + (1-d)*xOriginal(:,2), d*yOriginal(:,1) + (1-d)*yOriginal(:,2))
```

Setting `d = 0.5` we go back to the half-way case above.

---

Example:

```matlab
xOriginal(:,1) = linspace(0.2,0.5,100);
yOriginal(:,1) = 3 * cos(xOriginal(:,1)*10-2.5) + 3;

xOriginal(:,2) = linspace(0.6,0.8,100);
yOriginal(:,2) = cos(xOriginal(:,2)*20-13.5) + 1;

clf; hold on
plot(xOriginal(:,1),yOriginal(:,1))
plot(xOriginal(:,2),yOriginal(:,2))

plot((xOriginal(:,1)+xOriginal(:,2))/2,(yOriginal(:,1)+yOriginal(:,2))/2)
```

[image: resulting plot]

(the interpolated line is in orange)

Comment: Thanks! The half-way interpolation works pretty fine.
[link](https://imgur.com/a/e85SS5H)
So far I still could not figure out the weighted version. I tried:
`plot((xOriginal(:,1)+xOriginal(:,2))*0.2,(yOriginal(:,1)+yOriginal(:,2))*0.8)` but that does not show curves in between two curves that have been used for the interpolation.

Comment: @TobiK: Edited to make that part more explicit.

Comment: Thanks, with that clearification it worked out! I will check if I now have everything I need or if I really need to interpolate the 3-dimensional arrays as well (those contain current values and efficiencies). Since that would be another interpolation-type, I assume I should then start another question?

Comment: @TobiK: Yes, I think that would be quite a different question.