# Matlab interp2() gives 'monotonically increasing' error

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have many lines that represent a "z" value and want to interpolate at a specific value between them, at a specific x-axis location, to get the y-value. I'm trying `interp2()` but it throws a 'monotonically increasing' error.

The dataset below is a subset. I broke it out into xyz-1 and xyz-2 just for easy plotting in this question (i.e., making a repeatable example). How can I fix my `interp2()` or the inputs?

```
x1 = [0.02, 0.048, 0.108, 0.196, 0.279, 0.401];
y1 = [0.583, 0.43, 0.32, 0.279, 0.262, 0.259];
z1 = [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50];

x2 = [0.02, 0.048, 0.108, 0.196, 0.279, 0.401];
y2 = [0.747, 0.591, 0.435, 0.357, 0.326, 0.305];
z2 = [35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35];

x_all = [x1, x2];
y_all = [y1, y2];
z_all = [z1, z2];

plot(x1, y1, 'blue', 'DisplayName', 'z1')
hold on
plot(x2, y2, 'magenta', 'DisplayName', 'z2')
xlabel('x') 
ylabel('y') 
legend


want_x = 0.2;
want_z = 40;

need_y = interp2(x_all, y_all, z_all, want_x, want_z, 'linear')
```

Error:

```
Error using griddedInterpolant
The grid vectors must be strictly monotonically increasing.

Error in interp2>makegriddedinterp (line 228)
    F = griddedInterpolant(varargin{:});

Error in interp2 (line 128)
        F = makegriddedinterp({X, Y}, V, method,extrap);
```

[image]

Comment: The question is unclear for me. Can you describe more clearly?

Comment: I want to interpolate a point between the magenta and blue. Magenta line has a z-axis value of 50. Blue line has z-axis value of 35. I want to know, what is y-value if I am at x = 0.2 and z = 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`griddata`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) is your friend for these tasks, It uses `scatteredInterpolant` under the hood, but in my opinion is more user friendly.

Keeping the same example code you gave, replacing the last line with:

```
>> need_y = griddata(x_all,z_all,y_all,want_x, want_z)
need_y =
         0.329506024096386
```

The function can take vector inputs for `want_x` and `want_z` and return a vector output of `need_y` if you need to query more than one point.

You can also specify the interpolation method (`linear`, `cubic`, etc ...).

---

And just to make sure it worked as desired:

```
>> F = scatteredInterpolant(x_all.', z_all.', y_all.', 'linear');   %NOT y_all, z_all
need_y = F(want_x, want_z)
need_y =
         0.329506024096386 % same result, yay!
```

---

For more details about using `griddata`, you can have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23497688/3460361) to this question extremely similar to yours (just worded a bit differently): [Interpolation between two curves (matlab)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23494254/3460361)

Answer (score 0):

You can interpolate the value with:

```
x1 = [0.02, 0.04, 0.09, 0.184, 0.309, 0.667];
y1 = [0.586, 0.447, 0.34, 0.279, 0.256, 0.256];
z1 = [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50];

x2 = [0.022, 0.044, 0.076, 0.125, 0.184, 0.293, 0.509, 0.667];
y2 = [0.747, 0.6, 0.49, 0.41, 0.363, 0.326, 0.303, 0.3];
z2 = [35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35];

want_x = 0.2;
want_z = 40;

y1_ = interp1(x1, y1, want_x);
y2_ = interp1(x2, y2, want_x);
want_y = interp1([50 35], [y1_ y2_], want_z);
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks tough/tedious for the xn, yn case where n is large. Is there a way to collapse it, such as using `x_full = [x1 x2 x3 x4 x5];` (etc. for yn and zn). This wasn't in the original question I suppose, sorry for that, and thank you for your help

Comment: I would use an array and a loop to calculate all `yn_` and store them in a vector. Then you can interpolate with `interp1([z1 z2 ... zn], [y1_ y2_ ... yn_], want_z);`

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered here:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/637955-interp2-monotonically-increasing-error

quoting from that answer, in case the link breaks in the future:

interp2() is only for two-dimensional interpretation over a grid, not for interpolation of vectors. You need something like
F = scatteredInterpolatn(x_all, z_all, y_all, 'linear');   %NOT y_all, z_all
need_y = F(want_x, want_z);